# What is a raw representation?

Tags: python

I'm reading "Learn Python the hard way" (by Zed Shaw) and it says that `%r` is used for "raw representation and debugging".

I'm sorry for such a uninformed question, but I have no idea what does it mean.

Comment: It's the representation returned form the `repr` function. It's similar to `str` but intended for internal use rather than display. It can be useful to print an element regardless of its type. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: @PaulRooney You can answer below

Comment: @cricket I'm expecting it to be shut down as a dupe at any moment, so didnt think an answer was appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know `%s` is used for most strings, that just calls `str()` over the variable that is formatted.

`repr()`, on the other hand is used for `%r` and will return the "raw string", which is easiest seen on string variables.

```
>>> print("%r vs. %s" % ('42','42'))
'42' vs. 42
```

[Python printf String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#printf-style-string-formatting)

> `'r'` - String (converts any Python object using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)).
>   `'s'` - String (converts any Python object using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str)).

When it says it is useful for "debugging", imagine you had leading/trailing spaces in a string... the "raw" format would be more clear.

```
print("%r vs. %s" % ('  hello','  hello'))
'  hello' vs.   hello
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful